Discriminated union type narrowing nested array
I have the following type definition:
enum MixedResultType {
  Abstract = 'ABSTRACT',
  Section = 'SECTION',
}

type MixedSearchResult =
  | {
      type: MixedResultType.Abstract;
      data: Abstract[];
    }
  | {
      type: MixedResultType.Section;
      data: Section[];
    };

Abstract and Section share no common properties.
If I define an object with MixedSearchResult:
const result: MixedSearchResult = {
 type: MixedResultType.Abstract,
 data: abs as Abstract[],
};

I will get an error saying
Type 'Abstract[]' is not assignable to type 'Abstract[] | Section[]'

The end goal is to have a MixedSearchResult array with different type of search results.

Your code, as is, works fine.  Here is a TS playground. https://tsplay.dev/mqgxYw  Are you doing any other transformations?  Using a Pick or Omit someplace?

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] or the question risks being closed as lacking debugging details.

works as expected https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=5.4.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgZ2AJwIYGNhQLxQN5SoBcUAdgK4C2cEyUAvgLABQokUAyhJgJYD2pHPihwSFarQYsWEcVACyPAB4QAJgCUICcgBtgAFXDQ8LAJDwkaTEIDkMAEId96mAGF9NgDRmuvAbY4AUXcASQB5ADkvFiZmFjZoRRVVLlRkdAALTW09HDMAH3wzUwSSJLVs3QMjADoLFAxgAG5i1VRgYlhEBswAbQBdFuZTWNNCk2GSozLlCq0qw0ga32B+UiHTUzaOkhW1gY36IZZ0ASQoSmUZ5NT0rPnc3AmpyGu5nOql+qtgb2Htzq9YrPTadABMxXof02INMoigAEZPFAAPQoqC0ZB8OiQsz9GJAA

Guys, thank you for your help. It works indeed, i realised i have the same Abstract and Section types defined on my be clients as well, and i imported the types from the wrong location.
